# typing a straightline next to a dfrac?

Tags: scaling, brackets, fractions

I would like to type[image]

how do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you've loaded the `amsmath` and `amsfonts` packages, you can write something like

```
\[
  \left. 
    \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}^{\beta}}
         {\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}} 
  \right|_{\mathcal{F}_t}
\]
```

[image]

`\left` and `\right` allows you to using *grouping*-like symbols and resize them to match the height of the material bracketed.  In this case, you only have `|` which is not paired with anything else.  So we use `\left.` to fill in for the missing grouping symbol.

Regarding `\[...\]`, this is for displayed math expressions.  It is currently preferred over `$$...$$` as it handles various spacing issues better, among other things.

Comment: I trust you that this works and i will use it but can i ask how exactly does this make the | long?

Comment: you want the t outside the mathcal

Comment: also what is \[ \]? never used this before